# multilple hasclass combos

Tags: jquery, find

I'm having a bit of trouble getting around find and selecting multiple classes on div tags.

```
<div class='class1 class2 class3'></div>
```

This may have class1 ir class2 etc how would I select class1 ans class2 or class1 orclass3.

Im also having problems fiding $this or each element to display on show or hide.

Thanks

---

Sorry all, logged on to laptop now, right so ive tried $('div.class1,.class2.class3') etc and all permitations this and it doesnt work for me im afraid.

eg

```
<div class="benefits risk">
<div class"risk">
<div class="benefits">
```

I want to be able to:

```
$(.here).click(function(){
  if(  $('div')hasClass('benefits')) {
$(this).find('someotherdiv').show();

})
```

but on the hasclass be able to have AND/OR and unique hasclasses, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean finding element that has mor than 1 class you could use:

```
$(".class1.class2") // this will give you elements that have the 2 classes
$(".class1,.class2") // this will give you elements that have class1 or class2
```

if you mean check if it's has a class use

```
$("#mydiv").hasClass("class1") // this will return true or false
```

**note :**

- don't forget the `" "` inside the `$()` function
- no need for the `||` cause the `,` do the or logical operator

Answer (score 1):

commas are like OR

```
$('.class1, .class2, .class3')
```

concatenation like AND

```
$('.class1.class2.class3')
```

just like in CSS

Comment: Tried that and $(.class.class2,class1class3) $(class1)||(class2,class3)||(class2) foesnt work forme

Comment: I do not even understand what did you tried to do with this but it is in many ways wrong. Not one of it is like mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to select elements that have class1 *and* class2 *and* class3, you select

```
$(".class1.class2.class3")
```

If you'd like to select elements that have class1 *or* class2 *or* class3, you select

```
$(".class1, .class2, .class3")
```